# Can't get mertics values reported through Partition.ReportLoad

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to dynamically report the load against all the instances of my stateless service. The goal is to read the reported values from the code later on. So far I have the code to report some metrics and read them with FabricClient, but the numbers I get are always 0 no matter what I do. So here is how service is configured -

```
<StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MySvcType" InstanceCount="-1">
    <SingletonPartition />
    <LoadMetrics>
      <LoadMetric Name="MemoryInMb" />
      <LoadMetric Name="CPU" />
    </LoadMetrics>
</StatelessService>
```

The code that reports the metrics -

```
    protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await base.RunAsync(cancellationToken);

        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        PerformanceCounter ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

        while (true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            this.Partition.ReportLoad(new List<LoadMetric> { new LoadMetric("MemoryInMb", (int)ramCounter.NextValue()), new LoadMetric("CPU", (int)cpuCounter.NextValue()) });

            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
```

And here is the code I have to pull out those metrics -

```
        var partitions = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(new Uri("fabric:/MyApp/MySvc"));
        foreach (var partition in partitions)
        {
            var partitionLoad = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetPartitionLoadInformationAsync(partition.PartitionInformation.Id);

            var replicas = new List<Replica>();
            ServiceReplicaList replicaList = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetReplicaListAsync(partition.PartitionInformation.Id);
            replicas.AddRange(replicaList);
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(replicaList.ContinuationToken))
            {
                replicaList = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetReplicaListAsync(partition.PartitionInformation.Id, replicaList.ContinuationToken);
                replicas.AddRange(replicaList);
            }

            foreach(var replica in replicas)
            {
                var replicaLoad = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetReplicaLoadInformationAsync(partition.PartitionInformation.Id, replica.Id);
                var memoryReports = replicaLoad.LoadMetricReports.Where(r => r.Name == "MemoryInMb");
                var cpuReports = replicaLoad.LoadMetricReports.Where(r => r.Name == "CPU");
            }
        }
```

So I get back only one report per each metric I've defined and value is always 0. Any thoughts on what should I do to start retrieving the values that are reported in my stateless service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load metrics are buffered and sent to the cluster every five minutes. Maybe you're just not waiting long enough?

Comment: Turns out you are right. Nice! Do I have means to alter this period?

Comment: Never mind. Seems like I've figured the way to alter the interval at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-balancing.

Comment: Update - the previous link doesn't lead to the solution. Here is a correct one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472459/service-fabric-resource-balancer-uses-stale-reported-load.